# Intersecting boxes in pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, diagrams, 3d, pst-solides3d

I need to make a picture of some 3D boxes (i.e., parallelepipeds) that intersect themselves in some complicated ways, so I tried pst-solides3d.

Here's the minimal working example: A long and thin blue box should pierce a flat yellow box at its center.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psset{viewpoint=20 25 15,Decran=50,solidmemory}
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,2)
    \psSolid[name=longbox,
        object=parallelepiped,
        a=3,b=.2,c=.2,
        fillcolor=blue](.5,.5,.5)
    \psSolid[
        name=flatbox,
        object=parallelepiped,
        a=.25,b=2,c=2,
        fillcolor=yellow](.5,.5,.5)
    \psSolid[object=fusion,
        action=draw,
        base=flatbox longbox]
        (0,0,0)
    \composeSolid
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is very strange: A piece of the thin box became yellow. It seems that the package is unable to determine which pieces of surfaces are in front.

[image: output]

With the option `action=draw**`, the result is even worse:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more than the six polygon shapes of the blue cube to draw hidden surfaces. And, of course, all objects must be calculated with `action=none` except of the last one:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(3,3)
    \psset{viewpoint=20 25 15,Decran=50,solidmemory,action=none}
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,2)
    \multido{\rA=0.0+0.3,\iA=0+1}{11}{%
      \psSolid[name=l\iA, object=parallelepiped,a=0.3,b=.2,c=.2,
          fillcolor=blue](-0.75 \rA\space add .5 .5)}
    \psSolid[
        name=flatbox,
        object=parallelepiped, a=.25,b=2,c=2,fillcolor=yellow](.5,.5,.5)
  \def\List{l0 }
  \psforeach{\iA}{1,2,..,10}{\xdef\List{\List\space l\iA\space }}
    \psSolid[object=fusion,action=draw**,base=flatbox \List]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's now clear that the package is less powerful than I expected, so boxes need to be partioned manually.

Comment: it is _simple_ to define a new object, which does this  itself.